# Too many same sub queries? Is it possible to create variables in View? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

After adding several sub queries, this query takes about 8 seconds to run.

```
SELECT 
    a.ImageID, 
    COALESCE (a.[14ky], 0) + COALESCE (b.Labor, 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (e.MelTotal) AS sm FROM v_Mel e WHERE e.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (f.MelSetFee) AS sm FROM v_Mel f WHERE f.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE (SUM(DISTINCT c.), 0) AS Final14ky, 
    COALESCE (a.[14kw], 0) + COALESCE (b.Labor, 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (g.MelTotal) AS sm FROM v_Mel g WHERE g.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (h.MelSetFee) AS sm FROM v_Mel h WHERE h.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE (SUM(DISTINCT c.), 0) AS Final14kw, 
    COALESCE (a.[18ky], 0) + COALESCE (b.Labor, 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (i.MelTotal) AS sm FROM v_Mel i WHERE i.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (j.MelSetFee) AS sm FROM v_Mel j WHERE j.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE (SUM(DISTINCT c.), 0) AS Final18ky, 
    COALESCE (a.[18kw], 0) + COALESCE (b.Labor, 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (k.MelTotal) AS sm FROM v_Mel k WHERE k.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (l.MelSetFee) AS sm FROM v_Mel l WHERE l.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE (SUM(DISTINCT c.), 0) AS Final18kw, 
    COALESCE (a.Plat, 0) + COALESCE (b.Labor, 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (m.MelTotal) AS sm FROM v_Mel m WHERE m.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (n.MelSetFee) AS sm FROM v_Mel n WHERE n.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE (SUM(DISTINCT c.), 0) AS FinalPlat, 
    COALESCE (a.Pall, 0) + COALESCE (b.Labor, 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (o.MelTotal) AS sm FROM v_Mel o WHERE o.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE ((SELECT SUM (p.MelSetFee) AS sm FROM v_Mel p WHERE p.ImageID = a.ImageID), 0) + COALESCE (SUM(DISTINCT c.), 0) AS FinalPall, 
    a.[14ky], 
    a.[14kw], 
    b.Labor AS LaborTotal, 
    (SELECT SUM (v_Mel.MelTotal) AS sm 
     FROM v_Mel 
     WHERE v_Mel.ImageID = a.ImageID) AS MelTotal, 
    (SELECT SUM (v_Mel.MelSetFee) AS sm 
     FROM v_Mel 
     WHERE v_Mel.ImageID = a.ImageID) AS MelSettingTotal, 
    SUM(DISTINCT c.) AS SideStoneTotal, 
    a.[18ky], a.[18kw], a.Plat, a.Pall
FROM 
    v_itemM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    v_LaborCalc b ON a.ImageID = b.ImageID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    v_SideStone c ON a.ImageID = c.ImageID, v_Mel
GROUP BY 
    a.[14ky], a.[14kw], a.ImageID, 
    a.[18ky], a.[18kw], a.Plat, a.Pall, 
    b.Labor
```

There are some redundant queries (`MelTotal`, `MelSetting`). I read somewhere that I can't use variables because I'm using this query inside a view.
Is there a better way to write this? I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you could use Cross Apply or or just Left Join to a sub query that gets the sum for you

Comment: `sum(distinct field)` seems kind of dangerous.. you sure dont want distinct by ImageID?

Comment: My choice was to use Sum(Disctinct field) or Subquery. v_Sidestone is also a View and totaling there instead of using Subquery here.

Comment: Left Join didn't work well if there are multiple rows in v_Sidestone or v_Mel. That's a part of the reason that I used Sum Distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're actually getting the result you want from this query and your question about the sub queries is all you need assistance with, just create a sub-query to get the Sums you need from v_Mel and left join to it.

```
FROM 
    v_itemM a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN v_LaborCalc b ON a.ImageID = b.ImageID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN v_SideStone c ON a.ImageID = c.ImageID, 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select ImageID, 
                            SUM(MelTotal) MelTotal, 
                            SUM(MelSetFee) MelSetFee 
                     FROM v_Mel 
                     GROUP BY ImageID) d ON a.ImageID = d.ImageID
```

Then for you sub queries just use

```
COALESCE (d.MelTotal, 0)
COALESCE (d.MelSetFee , 0)
```

Then add `MelTotal` and `MelSetFee` to your group by

```
GROUP BY a.[14ky], 
    a.[14kw], 
    a.ImageID, 
    a.[18ky], 
    a.[18kw], 
    a.Plat, 
    a.Pall, 
    b.Labor,
    d.MelTotal,
    d.MelSetFee
```

Comment: ahhh, this make sense! I'll try and let you know if this works! Thank you so much.